# Write unlimited bytes to bytes.Buffer

Tags: go

When I run the following code

```
func writeBytes() ([]byte, error) {
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    dstBytes := bufio.NewWriter(&buf)
    writeTonsOfBytes(dstBytes)
    b := buf.Bytes()
    fmt.Println(len(b))
    return b, nil
}
```

I get the output

```
32768
```

Which is signaling to me that there must be a limit on my `bytes.Buffer` instance, which I can't find documentation for.

How can I write an unlimited number of bytes to a `bytes.Buffer`?

Comment: In order to write an unlimited number of bytes, you must first have an unlimited amount of memory?  But seriously, make sure `dstBytes.Flush()` is called and that `writeTonsOfBytes` is not writing exactly 32768.

Comment: @TimCooper I ran `dstBytes.Write([]byte("more stuff"))` followed by `dstBytes.Flush()` before getting `b := buf.Bytes()` and the number is the same.

Comment: What is the code for the `writeTonsOfBytes` function?

Comment: Actually it looks like the `dstBytes.Flush()` might have fixed the problem in my production code. Thanks @TimCooper. If you want to post an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Why are you using the `bufio.Writer` here? If you directly write into the `bytes.Buffer` and there would be an error after 32768 bytes you would get an error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no call to

```
dstBytes.Flush()
```

in the code. Any bytes that are currently unwritten to `buf` will remain unwritten, causing `buf` to have an incomplete record of the bytes written to `dstBytes` in `writeTonsOfBytes`.

It also explains why the number of written bytes would end up as a power of 2 because new bytes are written to the underlying buffer at such an increment.